# Spring boot not creating a bean from configuration even the properties are defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a weird problem, I am trying to integrate a custom library which defines few beans - which are supposed to be read by the spring boot application main class.

Below is my main class code snippet.

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.frameworks")
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.order.sample"
        , "com.abc.alberta.logging"
        , "com.abc.enterprise"
        , "com.abc.platformservices.connectors.oracle"
        , "com.abc.order.emailframework"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.order.sample.domain.model.entity",
        "com.abc.order.emailframework.domains"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.abc.order.sample.repository", "com.abc.order.emailframework.repositories"})
@Slf4j
public class TestApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
```

As you can see I have defined all possible annotation just out of frustration on the main class, since it is not creating a bean defined in the configuration class as shown below. (This is added as a **dependency into the current project using maven dependency** - Omitted other stuff.)

```
@Slf4j
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "config.framework", name = "security.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ApplicationProperties.class, SSLProperties.class, SecurityPolicyProperties.class})
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnWebApplication
    public ServletSecurityInterceptor springBootInterceptor() throws PolicyAdminServiceConfigurationException {
        CertificatePropertyContext samlCertificatePropertyContext = new CertificatePropertyContext(
            sslProperties.getTrustStoreType(), sslProperties.getTrustStoreClean(),
            sslProperties.getTrustStorePassword(), sslProperties.getTrustStoreCryptovaultLabel());
        return new SpringBootSecurityInterceptor(remoteSynchonizer(), applicationProperties.getNamespace(), applicationProperties.getName(), samlCertificatePropertyContext, subjectHelper);
    }

}
```

Properties defined in the main project - are as below

```
server:
  port: 8080
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    client-auth: none
    trust-store: C:\sample-app\src\main\resources\truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: changeit
    key-store: C:\sample-app\src\main\resources\keystore.jks
    key-store-password: changeit
    client-alias: client-common


config:
  frameworks:
    namespace: com.abc.sampleApp
    name: sample-app
    security:
      token:
        host: abc.deployment.int
      policy:
        endpoint: abc.deployment.int
      enabled: true
```

I wonder why this is not working while adding the same in other apps with just @SpringBootApplication annotation it works flawlessly. Am I missing something here from spring side in configuration?

**UPDATE**
com.abc.enterprise - contains SecurityConfiguration (as part of a maven dependency)
com.abc.order.sample - contains the TestApplication (as part of the application itself)

Comment: What packages are `SecurityConfiguration` and `TestApplication` classes placed in?

Comment: try to change setting to `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "config.framework.security.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)`

Comment: is `@ConditionalOnWebApplication` realy required here at all?

Comment: I am not sure about that @Andrey

Comment: I can't make changes in those files - those are library files. (jars included from a maven dependency)

Comment: Your YAML contains a property named `application.frameworks.security.enabled` and your `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation is looking for `config.framework.security.enabled`. The split between `prefix` and `name` also isn't quite right. They should be `config.framework.security` and `enabled` respectively. To see exactly which conditions are being evaluated and their results, trying starting your application with a command line argument of `--debug`.

Comment: try to make changes in your `application.yaml` as Andy pointed out: to `config.framework.security.enabled`.

Comment: Hi Andrey, it is my mistake I have messed it up while asking the question - sorry for the typo.

Comment: so the problem solved? if no please update initial post

Comment: Hello Andrey, the problem isn't solved yet, working on it - once solved I will update the question for other's reference. Thank you.

Comment: @BilboBaggins How do you run this application i.e. is it from eclipse/intelij ide? Is this an actual web-application or a single operation command line application? Are you able to see the application running on port 8080? Have you tried running with`--debug` to see if you can find anything in logs?